# ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameter.get('id') not getting the id

Tags: controller

i am using the controller for a vf page where string variable of currentpage id are getting null value.

controller-

```
public class CreateGiftButtonPageExtension
{
    public Gift__c gift{get;set;}
    public string RecordId{get;set;}
    public string leadid{get;set;}
    public string conid{get;set;}
    public CreateGiftButtonPageExtension()
    {
      conid=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ContactId');  
      leadid=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('LeadId'); 
      system.debug('leadid------>'+leadid);
      system.debug('conid------>'+conid);
        gift = new Gift__c();
        if(conid!=null){
        gift.Contact__c = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ContactId'); 
                RecordId = conid;
        }
        else { 
         gift.Lead__c = leadid; 
        RecordId = leadid; 
          }
        gift.Gift_Id__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_id');
        gift.Interest_Idea__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_interest');
        gift.Work_Location__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_work');
        gift.Gift_Reason__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_Reason');
        gift.Relationship__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_relationship');
        gift.City__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_city');
        gift.State__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_state');      
        gift.Age__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gift_age'); 
        gift.Status__c='Researching'; 
            }

    public pageReference toReceiveParameters()
    {

            insert gift;
            system.debug('gift---------->'+gift);
            return new pageReference('https://ap4.salesforce.com/'+gift.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have posted here, you never actually call `get('id')`, and I assume that the parameter isn't being set in the url when you request the page.

When you call the code to get parameters from the current page,

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ContactId');
```

it gets the corresponding parameter from the page url. In this case, the `ContactId`. If you set the `ContactId` parameter in the url, you should see it being retrieved in your page controller. For `ContactId` it would look something like:

```
https://...?ContactId=003XXXXXXXXXXXX&...
```

---

Also, if this is an extension, and not an independent page controller,

```
<apex:page StandardController="Gift__c" extensions="CreateGiftButtonPageExtension">
```

vs

```
<apex:page controller="CreateGiftButtonPageExtension">
```

you should define the constructor with a standard controller as a parameter:

```
public CreateGiftButtonPageExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
```